# Paperclip and Amazon S3 URL is too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

When the an image is stored to Amazon S3 using Paperclip the url of the image is too long:

e.g. http://s3.amazonaws.com/railsapp/Users/am/Desktop/railsapp/public/system/avatars/1/thumb/16110022.jpg?1171724004
(this is basically http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucketname]/[path on mac to image])

This is in my user model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                :styles => { :thumb => "100x100>", :medium =>"250x250>" },
                :default_style => :thumb,
                :default_url => "/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png",
                :storage => :s3,                    
                :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml"
```

How can I make the url shorter and so that it doesn't include the long link to the file?
At the same time, is there a way to prevent the original file (not the resized ones) form being saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried defining the `:path` option such as `:path => "avatars/:id/:style/:filename"`?

Comment: Hi there, what is the difference between :path and :url?

Comment: Just tried  -  :path => "/avatars/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"  -  and it worked well - thanks.  I am still confused about the purpose of url though

Comment: I don't know what `url` has as an effect on saving the file, I thought it was just something used during retrieving. I've also never set `url`, just `path`.

Comment: "path" is where the file is saved on the filesystem. "url" is the external-facing link to that file. Your path may be /usr/local/images/20.jpg and your URL could be: http://amazons3.com/assets/20.jpg